# Terminate .NET remoting async service call from client side

Tags: .net, .net-remoting

There is a .NET remoting service that usually takes a longer time. When a client makes an async request to the service and when client times out, I need to terminate the execution of server call. How do I do it ?

Current service mode: Singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there isn't a way, unless you can abort the TCP channel. Best to use an async delegate and abort that.

Comment: If we consider the Remoting object it self, rather than the specific method execution, would it be possible to destroy the remote object and mimic the required behaviour.

Comment: I suspect that is something empirical. Try it and report back.